# How to use && in an if statement

Tags: c

My program is below.

I want to change this line:

```
if(a==b || b==c)
```

to use `&&` instead of `||`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int digit, a, b, c;
    scanf("%d", &digit);
    a=digit/1000;
    b=digit/100%10;
    c=digit/10%10;
    if(a==b || b==c) // how to use && in this program
        printf("YES");
    else
        printf("NO");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "similar"? you are checking for an equality in your code.

Comment: you could do the equivalent `if (!((a!=b) && (b!=c)))`

Comment: what's the input / expected output

Comment: input: 123
output: no

Comment: How many digits are you working with?  If the number has 4 digits, then `a` gets the thousands digit, `b` gets the hundreds digit, and `c` gets the tens digit.  They’re all the same if `a` equals `b` _and_ `b` equals `c`. However, you’re not checking the last digit, and you’re presuming 4 digits rather than checking that you have 4 digits.  Also, output a newline at the end of your printing operations it ensures tidy and timely output on the command line.

Comment: use multiple if statements

Comment: i'm working 3 digits. and

Comment: if(!((a!=b) && (b!=c))) doesn't work. it displayes 112 --> yes

Comment: Then you are doing it wrong.  Using `”%3d”` in the format string would limit the input to at most three digits and one sign.  You are not getting the units digit, and you are getting the thousands digit (which will always be zero if you have a 3-digit number).  Your test is wrong if you want all digits the same. It is also wrong if you want any two digits to be the same (but the third can be different, or the same).

Comment: I think it should be `a=digit/100;` instead of `a=digits/1000;`, since you are trying to get the first of the 3 digits. If you want all your digits to be the same, you should use `&&` instead of `||` in the `if` statement so that you make sure that all digits are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are checking whether all digits are same, Now there is a mistake in your question. `if((a==b) || (b==c))` it will print **YES** if any of the two inputs are same. You don't want that.

So using && this equation is simply

```
if((a == b) && (b == c))
```

Thats it. I previously just converted your wrong eqution.
And you have to decrease your number also

```
a = digit % 10;
digit = digit / 10;
b = digit % 10;
digit = digit / 10;
c = digit % 10;
```

And without decreasing the number also it can be done

```
a = digit / 100;
b = digit / 10 % 10;
c = digit % 10;
```

Comment: Please edit the mistake in your question. Now it will work.

Comment: @LuckyTuvshee yes you are doing wrong here. Check your o/p for input 112. It will print yes if any of the two digits are similar. And please accept the answer if it resolved your query.

Comment: what is i/p you are giving?

Comment: if((a == b) && (b == c)) --> everything no.

Comment: input 111, 112, 123

Comment: Okk. I got it. You have to decrease that number also

Comment: And without decreasing also it can be done. See my edit answer

Comment: please explain about your convert :))

Comment: @LuckyTuvshee which convert or lines exactly?

Comment: Try it yourself using pen paper or use debugger. [This](https://sites.google.com/site/souvikghosh999/write-a-c-program-to-extract-and-print-all-digits-from-a-given-number) link will provide you some hint.

Comment: OK, thank u :) 
my input is 3digit. so first digit is digit/100 :))
i understand

Answer (score 1):

If a number contains three digits than the digits can be calculated using expressions `number % 10`, `number / 10 % 10` and at last `number / 100` or even better `number / 100 % 10`.

So you should write

```
int number, a, b, c;

//...

a = number % 10;
b = number / 10 % 10;
c = number / 100 % 10;

if ( a == b && b == c ) { /*...*/ }
else { /*...*/ }
```

However this approach is not good. The user can enter a number that contains for example only one digit or more than three digits.

You can use a general approach instead of the partial case of numbers with three digits.

Below there is a demonstrative program that shows how it can be done.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    const unsigned int Base = 10;

    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf("Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): ");

        unsigned int number;

        if (scanf("%u", &number) != 1 || number == 0) break;

        unsigned int digit = number % Base;

        while ((number /= Base) && (number % Base == digit)) digit = number % Base;

        if ( number == 0 )
        {
            printf("All digits of the number are the same and equal to %u\n", digit);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Digits of the number are not equal each other\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
nter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 111
All digits of the number are the same and equal to 1
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 211
Digits of the number are not equal each other
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```